# Javaから echo, パイプ, mecabを含むコマンドを実行して結果を文字列で得たい

Tags: java, shell

お世話になっております。さて、コマンドラインで

`echo "Javaで外部プロセスを実行する" | /usr/local/Cellar/mecab/0.996/bin/mecab -Owakati`

と叩くと `Java で 外部 プロセス を 実行 する` が返ってくる状態で次のようなコードを書きました。

```
public class MeCab {
    public static void execute()
    {
        try
        {
            String command = "echo \"Javaで外部プロセスを実行する\" | /usr/local/Cellar/mecab/0.996/bin/mecab --Owakati";

            String [] args = command.split(" ");
            Process process = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();
            InputStream is = process.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            int c;
            while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
                builder.append((char) c);
            }

            String text = builder.toString();

            int ret = process.waitFor();
            System.out.println(text);
            System.out.println(ret);
        }
        catch (IOException | InterruptedException e)
        {

        }

    }

    public static void main(String [] a )
    {
        execute();
    }
}
```

その結果

```
"Javaで外部プロセスを実行する" | /usr/local/Cellar/mecab/0.996/bin/mecab --Owakati

0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

となって期待通りに動作しません。mecabの標準入力に文章を与えて結果だけ受け取りたいのですが、どうしたらできるでしょうか？

なお、MeCabのJavaバインディングやKuromojiといった同種のプログラムのJava実装があることは知っていますが、今回は外部プロセスでMeCabを呼びたい事情があります。

開発環境は Mac OS X Ver. 10.14.4と

```
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

ですが、本番環境はCentOS 6になります。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String [] args = command.split(" ");
```

この行を次のように変更してみて下さい。

```
String[] args = {"/bin/sh", "-c", command};
```

パイプを使用するには、シェルを起動してからそのシェル内でコマンドを実行する必要があります。

Comment: FYI: 少し注意点を補足しておきます。この回答は正常に動作しない原因についてのみ回答しています。提示していただいたJavaのプログラムには、複数の改善すべき点（例外処理の実装方法など）があります。別の回答に対する@yukihaneさんのコメントにある[記事](http://www.ne.jp/asahi/hishidama/home/tech/java/process.html)はよく読んでおいた方がいいと思います。ちょっと長いですが、[私が書いた記事](https://qiita.com/tamura__246/items/5ed6d693480da428fbd5)も参考になるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

Qiitaの　[Javaで外部プロセス実行(システムコール)を行う](https://qiita.com/suzuki_y/items/212ae68059a2c340b79c)　という記事の２つ目のサンプルに 「外部プロセスを実行した結果を取得する(サンプル：mecabで形態素解析を行った結果を取得する)」というのがあります。

参考になるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 本質問への回答という点からすると、質問タイトルに有る echo, パイプが登場しないので妥当ではなさそうです。また、一般的なJavaでの外部プロセス実行の実装例という点からすると、あまり適切なサンプルであるとは思えません。実際には「[後から読み込むと駄目な理由 - Java外部プロセス起動メモ(Hishidama's Java Process Memo)](http://www.ne.jp/asahi/hishidama/home/tech/java/process.html#h4_NG_after)」のような点に注意する必要があります。